# Not working fork

Tags: maintenance, fork

I have watched several video tutorials about how to service a fork and decided to try to open and clean my Suntour Nex 4610 fork . I didn't do anything besides cleaning and lubricating the tube. I didn't touch the spring or the suspension cylinder inside. But now when I reattach the two parts (without tightening the bolts) the fork stops moving even when I apply a lot of pressure.

What could be the reason for this problem?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but this appears to be the manual for your fork. I would rely on it more than video tutorials. http://www.ktm-bikes.at/picts/UserManualsPDFs/Suntour-Gabel-CR-8Vneu.pdf

Comment: If that is not the correct manual, Suntour has owner's manuals listed by year on this page: http://www.srsuntour-cycling.com/service/owners-manuals/

Comment: Thank you for info , but there weren't any instructions for repair and service .

Comment: Wow. That sucks. Sorry, I just assumed that they'd be in there.

Comment: Try [this](http://forums.mtbr.com/tooltime/suntour-xcr-fork-maintenance-disassembly-repair-fix-service-753451.html)

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing pictures it's hard to figure out what has happened. Suntour use 'throw away' sealed damper units (the suspension tube) so not many parts to go wrong such as wrong oil volume and weight on other forks.

I would think that you've misaligned the lock out adjustment when you've put the fork back together and it's permanently locked out. The other option is you've put the spring in incorrectly but this would suggest you struggled getting the fork together.

Check out this [workshop manual](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&ved=0CHEQFjAI&url=http://veloline.by/%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B0%25D1%2581%25D1%2582%25D0%25B5%25D1%2580%25D1%2581%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B0%25D1%258F/manual/item/download/29_fc146c9f693c91f39533d2062a1666cb&ei=NMGVUvDsI6H9ywPnwYHQBQ&usg=AFQjCNEBABsDKT6qGMNEXbDQqNli-SWMHQ&sig2=Hh1cRPzsJi1VnYpqp5ijMA&bvm=bv.57155469,d.bGQ) it has the damper on page 96 and an exploded view on 135. Sorry it's a link straight to the PDF was all I could find.